# What is the first movie to show bloopers at end credits?

Tags: first-appearance, credits

I am not asking about post credit scene; I am asking about bloopers.
I've done research and found "[*Rush Hour* (1998)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_Hour_%281998_film%29)" is the first movie to show bloopers at the end of the movie. Are there any older examples than this movie?

Comment: Off-topic, but just to throw this out there: a post credit scene is called a "stinger".

Comment: Not exactly what you're after, but as a point of interest, [blooper reels have been around since as early as 1936](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g40SeAyq81g).

Comment: Why isn't anyone posting Smokey and the Bandit....meaning the first one??

Comment: @JohnHein Somebody did but due to being detail lacking answer it got deleted. You can also present it as your answer but remember to give a detailed answer rather then the comment you provided as an answer.

Comment: Liar Liar is 1 year older than Rush Hour and includes bloopers.

Comment: Rush Hour? I thought it was a long running Jackie Chan tradition before this,..

Answer (score 8):

[This article](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/10/movies/hot-pursuit-and-other-films-elevate-the-art-of-the-blooper-reel.html?_r=0) credits the movies [Being There](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078841/?ref_=nv_sr_1) (1979) and [Smokey and the Bandit II](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078841/?ref_=nv_sr_1) (1980) as being the early pioneers of the art.

Another site listed [Hooper](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077696/?ref_=nv_sr_3) (1978) with Burt Reynolds, as being the earliest example of this in a movie. This makes sense because the [wikipedia article on bloopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blooper) does credit Burt Reynolds and Jackie Chan with being known for putting bloopers in their ending credits.

[image]

I will update if I am able to find any earlier examples. Also I should mention that the wikipedia article mentions the earliest known "bloopers" to have been popularized on tv and radio as early as the 1930's, but the question specifically asks for the **first movie** to show bloopers **at the end of the movie** (ie in the credits) so I've limited my answer to that criteria.

Comment: Not earlier, but 1981's Cannonball Run is another Burt Reynolds movie that did it.